# ServiceStack GetRawBody() used to get duplicate headers?

Tags: http-headers, servicestack

I need to access HTTP headers that have duplicate values.  I'm currently using:

```
base.Request.Headers;
```

which gives me a Dictionary, and that means you cannot have a duplicate key.  But for HTTP requests duplicate keys are valid.  I found I can use:

```
base.Request.GetRawBody();
```

and that might give me access to the data where I can extract the headers I'm looking for?  I'm not very familiar with how to do that, and I was also wondering if there was a simpler way I'm missing?  Seems like I should be able to access headers that are part of a valid HTTP request header?

EDIT:
I found this reference:

HTTP RFC2616 available here says:
Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded

This makes me question if it is legal in the first place to have duplicates, or if they must be combined first, so:

```
my-duplicate-header:value1
my-duplicate-header:value2
```

would come in as:

```
my-duplicate-header:value1,value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although sending duplicate headers is allowed as mentioned in the spec, applications, in general, should properly sanitize header input values to disallow them. Allowing them could potentially make your website vulnerable to [HTTP response splitting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting).

Take a look at the example in the above link.

Some browsers will even bark at your guests if such a duplication is present. take a look at the warning in this [example](https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/201637494-What-is-the-Duplicate-Headers-Warning-)

Just my $0.2

Comment: Interesting.  The RFC is so vague about hard requirements on this that it is unclear when there are competing views.  When you say, "duplicate headers are allowed" do you mean the key:value1, value2 form?  or duplicate keys?

Comment: By "duplicate headers" I meant "duplicate keys". I've seen places where having duplicate keys was needed. But section 4.2 of RFC 2616 clearly indicates that the comma-separated format is the legitimate way to handle them. (cause with the "duplicate keys" format you get the "response splitting attacks" issue I mentioned earlier).